# OpenVZ container - Can't set nf_conntrack_max

Tags: iptables

My question is does the Host Node and a container both have the same "nf_conntrack_max" ?

When i check on the host vs the container these are the results:

Host Node

```
[root@echo ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
524288
```

OpenVZ Container

```
[root@delta ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
65536
```

But when i try and change the value on the container i run into a couple issues.

This is how i would normally increase the value which works perfects on the host node.

```
[root@echo ~]# echo 1524288 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
[root@echo ~]#
[root@echo ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
1524288
```

Same thing run on the container

```
[root@delta ~]# echo 1524288 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
[root@delta ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
65536
```

What i don't understand is why i am having an issue raising the value on the container. Both the host node and the container are running Centos 6.6 and i was using root.

***EDIT***
I've tried running `sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=1524288` in the container but still seem to have an issue.

```
[root@delta ~]# /sbin/sysctl -a|grep -i nf_conntrack_max
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 65536
net.nf_conntrack_max = 65536
[root@delta ~]# sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=1524288
error: "Invalid argument" setting key "net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the host node and containers have seperate "nf_contract_max" values you are unable to raise a containers "nf_conntrack_max" higher then the host nodes "nf_conntrack_max".

For example; if your host node has a max of 65536 you will not be able to raise your containers max past 65536.

Simply raise the host nodes limit and then raise the containers limit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need just set conntrack in HN and restart CT.

Answer (score 0):

In a container you can check the limits with:

```
# /sbin/sysctl -a|grep -i nf_conntrack_max
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 2600000
net.nf_conntrack_max = 2600000
```

Set with (in the container):

`sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=32384`

However the maximum is the net.nf_conntrack_max value which it usually starts at anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've just edited the question but im still getting the "Invalid argument" error.

Comment: If you try and set it greater than net.nf_conntrack_max you will get an "Invalid argument" error.

Comment: I understand now so how would i raise "net.nf_conntrack_max" ? On my Centos 5 boxes i would just use 'echo 1524288 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_conntrack_max' and be fine.